# Regex with decimal number that must be specific number

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a regex for numbers like those

```
+2.25
-9,75
+02,50
-10.00
```

What I have done so far is this **^([-+]\d{2}[.,][00|25|50|75]{1,2})$**

```
1- [-+] = obligatory at the beginning
2- \d{2} = any number between 0 and 99
3- [.,] = separator can be .or,
4- [00|25|50|75]{1,2} = input must be 00 or 25 or 50 or 75
```

The number 4- is not working as you can test here https://regex101.com/.

What I want and what I don't want as results

```
-9.75 Good
-9.77 Bad
```

the end must always be **00** or **25** or **50** or **75**

Comment: it probably also makes sense to make the + at the beginning optional

Comment: What is the desired output?

Comment: Also `\d{2}` matches any digit 0-9 exactly two times. Meaning that you wont pick up the first two inputs since they are not double digit.

Comment: Complementary information added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to accept 1 or 2 numbers first.

```
^[-+]\d{1,2}[.,](00|25|50|75)$
```

the only modification to your regex: \d{1,2}, it accepts one or two digits.

Another option:

```
^[-+]\d?\d[.,](00|25|50|75)$
```

\d?\d makes the first digit optional.

You can test it [here](https://regex101.com/r/VMWxjL/2/) and [here](https://regex101.com/r/Le8t26/1)